# iOS imageView inside DetailView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, menu, uiimageview

- I have simple Master-Detail Application: Menu with 3 Tabel Ciew Cells and if I click it I see DetailView with clicked cell's description ("Button 1", "Button 2" or "Button 3") on the center.
- I want to replace this text to imageView with different image: If I click first cell, I see first image, second cell - second image etc.

My DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)configureView
{
     if(self.detailItem)
     {
          self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
     }
}
```

- How to check cell's id and set necessary image?

Comment: what u want ?? explain in sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

Okay, well you need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath in your table view controller in that case.

Something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Set properties of your detail view controller here
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        // Create and show image view 1

    } else if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        // Create and show image view 2
    }

}
```

Further info here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/didselectrowatindexpath/info

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not correct! Master-detail application creates Table View and it's not a button, it's Table View Cell. See updated post please